# Plugin [id: 'org.springframework.boot', version: '2.1.7.RELEASE'] was not found in any of the following sources

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

I have recently started with gradle and trying to run a spring boot application with gradle in my mac machine.

When I am trying to do local build, I am getting below error:

[image]

My build.gradle is the default which gets downloaded from spring initializr with few dependencies.

```
plugins {
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.7.RELEASE'
id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.7.RELEASE'
id 'java'
}

group = 'com.ank'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
 maven {
    url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
 }
}

dependencies {
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
}
```

My JAVA_HOME is at path: `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home`

I have tried building the same in Intellij, Eclipse and in terminal by `gradle --stacktrace`. It fails everywhere with the same error.

My gradle version is 5.6.

Comment: I think this plugin is not available in maven central.

Comment: Are you sure that your JAVA_HOME is on your PATH?

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: This question is for a more advanced version and contains more answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60017092/plugin-id-org-springframework-boot-version-2-2-4-release-was-not-found. Also check plugin documentation: https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.springframework.boot

Answer (score 5):

It is available on [`gradlePluginPortal()`](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.springframework.boot) or [`mavenCentral()`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-gradle-plugin); both repositories provide it. The current version is [`2.7.1`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/2.7.1) and not [`2.1.7.RELEASE`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/2.1.7.RELEASE) or some imaginary non-existent version `2.7.2`.
As one can see, `2.1.7.RELEASE` has vulnerabilities from dependencies, so better use `2.7.1`.

Make sure the `buildscript` block or the `settings.gradle` has plugin `repositories` defined.
I mean, this one project `repositories` block there (with a plugin repository), is in fact useless.

To be precise; One has to define plugin `repositories`, either in the `buildscript` block:

```
buildscript {
    // Gradle plugin repositories
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    // Gradle plugin dependencies
    dependencies {}
}
```

Or inside file `settings.gradle`:

```
import org.gradle.api.initialization.resolve.RepositoriesMode

// Gradle plugin repositories
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

// Java project repositories
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.PREFER_SETTINGS)
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

---

Only then the `plugins` block in a module will know about these `repositories`:

```
// Gradle plugin dependencies
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.1'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.12.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

// Java project repositories
// not required when using settings.gradle
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

// Java project dependencies
dependencies {}
```

Also see the [Spring Boot Gradle Plugin Reference Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started).

Comment: The link that you included uses version 2.7.2: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started:
```plugins {
 id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.2'
}```. It doesn't seem non-existent.

Comment: @Kevin It exists but one dependent package apparently has not been published (possibly until yesterday). It is being claimed it does now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73065110/missing-spring-boot-buildpack-platform/73065289#73065289

Answer (score 0):

Try setting this in `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
  id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.2'
  id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.12.RELEASE'
  id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
  testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
  testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
  useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

SpringBoot configuration errors can be easily solved by checking generated files -> [here](https://start.spring.io/)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem.
I solve this problem in intellij disabling the gradle online mode.

Answer (score -1):

Add the following repository. `org.springframework.boot:org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin` not available in maven central:

```
repositories {
    maven {
      url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
  }
```

Comment: I did the suggested changes. Still it's throwing the same error.

Comment: Can you update the full `gradle.build` file content after modification to the post?

Comment: Updated the build file.

Comment: Are you getting the exact same error message or a different message? You may include both `mavenCentral()` and the plugin one you have added. By the way, with `https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/` and your build file, my build is succeeding. Let me take a look again.

Comment: Especially the message part `Searched in the following locations` is expected to be different when you do a clean build.