# Plugin [id: 'org.springframework.boot', version: '2.2.4.RELEASE'] was not found in any of the following sources:

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

I have just downloaded the springboot project from http://start.spring.io/. After running it I got this error.

```
* What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'org.springframework.boot', version: '2.2.4.RELEASE'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.springframework.boot:org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin:2.2.4.RELEASE')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Can any one please suggest what is root cause.

Comment: check your internet connection

Comment: This is also the error you get when you screw up your `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` setting.  I had inadvertently set mine to an invalid location and got this error.  I imagine it could no longer verify the repository's https certificate.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I would recommend you to run `gradle build` command in your terminal.
After this, do a gradle sync.

Must be some problem with your IDE.

Hope this solves your issue.

Answer (score 21):

Accepted answer didn't work for me. I am able to resolve this after adding **settings.gradle** file in project root with,

settings.gradle:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        maven { url "<Repo_URL>" }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer from my perspective. if you are behind a corporate firewall and could not access gradle plugin repository and have your own repo - use the above to set that for plugin management.

Comment: You cannot reach maven central?

Answer (score 7):

In my case I had configured a proxy from my job in the gradle.properties file, but I wasn't through their VPN.

If this is also your case, you can just comment the lines in that file, or just connect to the VPN if it is possible.

Comment: Also can be an issue with wrong port in proxy settings or in `gradle.properties`

Answer (score 2):

**I could solve it as follows:**

In the build.gradle file add the following lines:


[image: Add these lines to build.gradle]


Then you must open a **command window** and enter the folder where you have the project and execute the following order:

**gradle build**

That's it, with this your error must be solved ... Greetings !!!

Comment: Which command window?  It doesn't work from the terminal: " gradle : The term 'gradle' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, "

Comment: @Markus youe need to insall gradle https://gradle.org/install/

Answer (score 2):

None of the answers above worked for me, what fixed it was removing '.RELEASE' from the version ([see here](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.springframework.boot))

```
id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.5.4.RELEASE"
```

to

```
id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.5.4"
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem, too. I used the OpenJDK 1.8 in my Spring Boot Project which for whatever reason created these complications, so I changed it to Amazon Corretto JDK 11 and the sync and build ran without errors.

If you use IntelliJ I would recommend you to change your SDK in the Project Structure/Project, Project Structure/Modules and Project Structure/SDKs and finally change the Gradle JVM to the new JDK version in Settings/Build, Execution, Deployment/Build Tools/Gradle/GradleJVM.

Answer (score 2):

**You are using incompatable gradle versions!!!**

Check your gradle version:
**your gradle version**: `gradle --version`
**project version**: `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` has property `distributionUrl` where you can find project version

If there is difference between your gradle version and project gradle version just download and use project gradle version https://gradle.org/releases/

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too, after trying out all the above it wasn't resolved. Then by trying gradle with other versions and other version of JDK, then I figured out that it was due to SSL authentication issue. In my case I have to add the security certificates from my local nexus repository to the JDK used by Gradle and the problem was resolved.

You can download the SSL certificates by browsing to the nexus repository manager and downloading it from the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Guys for me was just old Gradle version, I updated following this link https://gradle.org/install/. For Ubuntu:

```
$ mkdir /opt/gradle
$ unzip -d /opt/gradle gradle-7.0.2-bin.zip
$ ls /opt/gradle/gradle-7.0.2
LICENSE  NOTICE  bin  getting-started.html  init.d  lib  media
```

Answer (score 0):

Team adding below in `build.gradle` will help solve the issue:

```
allprojects  {
    apply plugin: 'maven'
    apply plugin: "io.spring.dependency-management"

    group = 'com.wnp'
    version = '6.5.0-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. The reason was in my Windows machine path to the java certs in `gradle.properties` file having in correct format (i.e / instead of \ ) `systemProp.javax.net.ssl.trustStore=<JAVA_HOME>\\lib\\security\\cacerts`

Answer (score 0):

I had the Gradle offline mode enabled in IntelliJ. After I turned that off in the Gradle Window, I was able to build using Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, gradle doesn't log the actual issue. Instead it always wrapped with exception,

```
org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'org.springframework.boot', version: '2.7.14'] was not found in any of the following sources:
```

If its working with local repository or any other old repository, then issue might be related to certs.

In my case, i have provided the below configurations in gradle.properties on macOS

```
systemProp.javax.net.ssl.trustStore=/dev/null
systemProp.javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=KeychainStore
```

Answer (score -1):

The default build.gradle file generated by spring.io only includes mavenCentral in repositories. Not sure why, but once in a while, this error shows up. Add jcenter as well in there, it should work. 
To be more clear repositories could look like following after change

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Answer (score -2):

First of all you need to understand the problem. Why did this error occur ?
The lines in build.gradle file

```
plugins {
       id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.4.RELEASE'
       id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
       id 'java'
}
```

tells gradle that "spring" and "java" are required for you project to build.
Plugins are task in gradle.

Now for compiling the project the gradle has to bring these plugins specified. for that it
will look in the repositories that you have specified. in

```
repositories {
            mavenCentral()
}
```

So There must not be any problem with the Code. Refreshing must solve

Answer (score -2):

In my case I was on vpn and it blocked the traffic from above repositories.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).