# Missing spring-boot-buildpack-platform

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

I'm using gradle plugin:

```
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.2'
```

And getting this.  Am I missing something?

```
 Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-buildpack-platform:2.7.2.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-buildpack-platform/2.7.2/spring-boot-buildpack-platform-2.7.2.pom
     If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but 
without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... 
}' of the repository declaration.
     Required by:
         project : > 
org.springframework.boot:org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin:2.7.2 > 
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.7.2
   > Could not find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-loader-tools:2.7.2.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-loader- 
   tools/2.7.2/spring-boot-loader-tools-2.7.2.pom
     If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
 Required by:
     project : > 
org.springframework.boot:org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin:2.7.2 > 
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.7.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When repository `gradlePluginPortal()` doesn't have it, try `mavenCentral()`:

```
runtimeOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-buildpack-platform:2.7.1'
```

But there no version `2.7.2` yet. Not sure if these versions would have to match, but in case of, downgrading to `id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.1'` might be your best chance.
Just [see for yourself](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-buildpack-platform), it's imply not there. Please don't ask me why they've not published it.

---

When versions can be mixed, one can use `resolutionStrategy` to change the version it will resolve:

In file `settings.gradle`:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    resolutionStrategy {
        eachPlugin {
            if (it.requested.id.getName() == 'org.springframework.boot') {
                if (it.requested.id.id == 'spring-boot-buildpack-platform') {
                    it.useModule('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-buildpack-platform:2.7.1')
                }
                println ">> ${it.target}"
            } else {
                println ">  ${it.target}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Either with `it.useModule` or `it.version`. `println ">> ${it.target}"` is just there for tesing.
Option B will work while the public API of `spring-boot-buildpack-platform` hasn't changed.

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com is an eventually consistent view of Maven Central. If you go directly to Maven Central, you'll see that the artifact is already there: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-buildpack-platform/2.7.2/